# How to enable kernel pstore?

Tags: kernel-modules, debugging

I'm trying to enable the kernel persistent storage (pstore) in order to help debug a module which malfunctions and freezes my laptop on suspend, but I'm having difficulties doing so.
My kernel (4.1.20) config with related parameters is

```
# gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep PSTORE
CONFIG_CHROMEOS_PSTORE=m
CONFIG_PSTORE=y
CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_PSTORE_PMSG is not set
# CONFIG_PSTORE_FTRACE is not set
CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM=m
```

I have also tried loading the `ramoops` module, but when I do

```
# cat /sys/module/pstore/parameters/backend
(null)
```

it doesn't seem to have enabled anything. /sys/fs/pstore is empty as well, altough mount says that it is mounted. I have tried to panic my kernel using [this](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/sparc/+/refs/heads/master/tools/testing/selftests/pstore/pstore_crash_test) but nothing showed up.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even supposed to work on a normal laptop, or am I completely in the dark? I could not find very much while looking for this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine a piece of memory that survives a reboot. Then it's probably the easiest approach to pass that via kernel parameters, see
the [ramoops Documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/ramoops.rst#n49) in the kernel tree.